# Get Android List Selected Background Color

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity uses a `TableView layout` and I have it coded to set the background to a color (drawable state list) when pressed/focused.

I would like the color to be the theme's pressed/focused color of the `ListView`.

Does anyone know the android default color for the ListView pressed or focused state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `android.R.drawable.list_selector_background`. Its the statelist drawable that android uses to show pressed focussed and other states on listviews.